# FragmentPagerAdapter instantiateItem working with Fragments?

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

i try to get my FragmentPagerAdapter working, but the examples are a bit to easy for real life :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position)
{
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position)
        {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.favorites_fragment;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.nearby_list_fragment;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index cant be mapped to fragement:" + position);
        }

    final View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    viewPager.addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}
```

As i'm want to use Fragments im already confused my this method as all example i could find inflate a view instead of create fragment there. How to do this ?

PS: Im using the ActionBarSherlock lib 4.1...

Thanks,
Jens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? Show the definition of your class. You have to extend `FragmentPagerAdapter` and implement `public abstract Fragment getItem(int position)` to return your fragments. Do *not* override `instantiateItem()` it already does the right thing in `FragmentPagerAdapter`.